# How do I test executorService in a method that process async data

Tags: java, unit-testing, executorservice

I have a method that process inputStream in a separate thread than that of outputStream for memory efficiency. (The save only accepts an inputStream)

The code works manually but to test it using junit, there is always a timeout because the test does not run the `save` in a different thread and waits for the rest of the code below to complete.

Do we have a solution for this? I tried the Guava's `MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()` but that did not help.

The goal is to test that the file is saved using the `save` method.

```
  public void generate(Trigger trigger) {

        PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();

        try {
            // Connect the PipedOutputStream to the PipedInputStream
            pipedOutputStream.connect(pipedInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An internal error occurred while connecting pipedInputStream to pipedOutputStream", e);
        }

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            client.save(pipedInputStream);
            try {
                pipedInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("An internal error while closing piped Stream", e);
            }
        });

        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream;

        try {
            zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(pipedOutputStream);

            ZipEntry csvEntry = new ZipEntry("test.csv");
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(csvEntry);

            generate(zipOutputStream, pipedOutputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

PS: `zipOutputStream` and `pipedOutputStream` are closed in the `generate` method.